# How do I get an array of objects when uploading files?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I have a request that allows to upload multiple files. But in the response I get data in the form of a single object. How do I get the response an array of objects?

Will I have to create another service?

**controller:**

```
@Post('upload')
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
async uploadFile(@UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File, @Req() request: Request) {
  const files = await this.fileService.create({
    name: file.originalname,
    path: file.originalname,
    type: file.originalname.split('.').pop(),
    size: file.size,
    user: request.user.user_id,
    parent: request.body.parent || undefined,
  });

  return files;
}
```

**service:**

```
  async create(data: any): Promise<any> {
    return this.repository.save(data);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently in your code, the controller handles only one file. to handle multiple files, you need to use `FilesInterceptor`, and `UploadedFiles` decorators.

So your code would be changed to something like this:

```js
import { Express } from 'express';
import { UploadedFiles } from '@nestjs/common';
import { FilesInterceptor } from '@nestjs/platform-express';

@Post('upload')
@UseInterceptors(FilesInterceptor('files'))
async uploadFile(@UploadedFiles() files: Array<Express.Multer.File>, @Req() request: Request) {
  // rest of code
}
```

or if each field has a unique name:

```js
@Post('upload')
@UseInterceptors(FileFieldsInterceptor([
  { name: 'avatar', maxCount: 1 },
  { name: 'background', maxCount: 1 },
]))
uploadFile(@UploadedFiles() files: { avatar?: Express.Multer.File[], background?: Express.Multer.File[] }) {
  console.log(files);
}
```

[more](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload#multiple-files).